# Is it possible to use Lua to obtain the current working directory?

Tags: luatex, currfile

Package `currfile` with the `abspath` option can obtain the absolute path of the current file. However, it relies on running `pdflatex` with the `-recorder` flag.
Would it be possible to achieve the same objective using `lualatex`?

Note that `lualatex` has the same set of command line flags as `pdlflatex`, so, naturally `currfile` would work in `lualatex` just as it would work in `pdflatex`. 
The challenge is to use `lua` to extract the current folder information within the text *without* relying on the `-recorder` flag.

Comment: lualatex has the same `--recorder` option

Comment: Of course. The idea is to use lua from within the text to extract the current folder without using the `-recorder` option.

Comment: Oh OK, your wording seemed to imply the option was pdftex specific. I have it on good authority a lua answer is imminent:-)

Comment: What about simply using the command `\currfilepath` from the currfilepackage?

Comment: Possible, but cumbersome. You have to remember to use the `-record` flag. The solution below is useful in circumstances where you use `lualatex` anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>Peer pressure once again. `:)`</sup>

IIRC, pure Lua has no built-in way to find out the current working directory without resorting to trickery. Thankfully, LuaTeX is shipped with the amazing [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/), which is a *"library developed to complement the set of functions related to file systems offered by the standard Lua distribution."*

The [reference section](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference) of the LFS manual indicates a way of achieving what we want:

> **`lfs.currentdir ()`**
>
> Returns a string with the current working directory or `nil` plus an error string.

There we go! Now let's write our `.tex` file based on this idea:

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\workingdir{\unexpanded\expandafter{\directlua{tex.write(lfs.currentdir())}}}

\begin{document}

Hello, I'm in \workingdir

\texttt{\meaning\workingdir}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to egreg for providing the `\edef` version instead of my original `\newcommand` approach; that way, it should avoid problems with special characters in the path, and if put in the preamble of the main document, the value won't change when `\workingdir` is used in an `\input` file.

Here's the sample output from my machine:

[image: Quack]

There we go! `:)`

**Update:** If we don't want to "freeze" the working directory value, I believe we can rely on my first attempt using `\newcommand` instead of using `\edef`:

```
\newcommand{\actualworkingdir}{%
\unexpanded\expandafter{\directlua{tex.write(lfs.currentdir())}}}
```

That way, `lfs.currentdir()` is always issued on demand. Please bear in mind that the difference of both approaches is quite substantial:

[image: Quack]

Comment: @David: classified information. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda with respect  *"the value won't change when \workingdir is used in an `\input` file."*, I think that an `\actualworkingdir` is even more  interesting. Could you add this to your nice answer?

Comment: @Fran: Sure, I'm just not sure the best way of achieving it. `:)` I will consult the TeX demigods in the chatroom and report back later on.

Comment: @Fran: I wrote something along those lines. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Many thakns, but I am testing both macros with a main document  in `/tmp` and a subdocument  in `/tmp/subdoc` but in the four cases I always obtain only  `/tmp` . However  with `\meaning` the display is different, as you showed. On other hand, I obtain the same results without `\unexpanded\expandafter`, so it is really needed?

Comment: @Fran: I will take a look later on. `:)` I think we haven't got any problems so far because Unix paths go with `/` instead of \; I suppose `\unexpanded` is needed mostly because of a potential special character in the path.