# How to obtain absolute path of a file

Tags: tex-core, latex3, external-files, paths

Many languages provide functions to obtain the `absolute path` of a file. I wonder if Tex/LaTex  has also such macros.

In the following example, given a file name, test if this file really exists. Then, if yes, output its absolute path(including file name) `from root` like `/home/foo/bar/myfile` or `/c/Program Files/foo/bar/myfile.tex`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\getabsolutepath{m}{
  \file_if_exist:nTF {#1}
  {
    % output the absolute path of the file name #1
  }
  {do some other things}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
% Given that the current path names "cp". A file named "a.tex" locates in its subdirectory "sub". 
% The typesets of the following invokations of \getabsolutepath should be absolutely the same when file "a" really exists because they refer to the same file.
\getabsolutepath{sub/a}
\getabsolutepath{./sub/a}
\getabsolutepath{./sub/a.tex}
\getabsolutepath{../cp/sub/a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file

Comment: Thank you for this info. Anyway, I don't think this meets my requirement. Those solutions needs working with `\input` ...and so on. What I want is just giving a file name and obtain its absolute path from root if the file really exists.

Comment: Take a look at [`\CurrentFilePath`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf)

Comment: Would you show me an example?

Comment: @Ingmar \CurrentFilePath doesn't give the absolute path. You need the currfile package (and you must use the --recorder option) to get the full absolute path of a file.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Would you give an answer?

Comment: Related: Lua solution [luatex - Is it possible to use Lua to obtain the current working directory? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229394/is-it-possible-to-use-lua-to-obtain-the-current-working-directory)

Comment: @user202729 Thank you! I'll learn it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kpsewhich` although for files found relative to the working directory, you may want to have `$PWD` rather than `.` in the path so the full path is reported. This command is allowed without `--shell-escape` in the default configuration of texlive (and I think also miktex)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\getabsolutepath#1{\input{|kpsewhich "#1"}}

\begin{document}

\getabsolutepath{article.cls}

\getabsolutepath{plain.tex}

\getabsolutepath{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

called by:

```
TEXINPUTS=$PWD: pdflatex  cc434
```

Comment: Side note, use `@@input` for an expandable version, I think. With some additional complications of everyeof etc.

Comment: @user202729 hmm `-c` appears not to work in restricted mode , I'd better edit

Comment: @David Carlisle The above code failed to pass complilation in my computer (win7+miktex). showed `(e:\MyOffice\Emacs_Related\Miktex\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd) (
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.2 e:/MyOffice/Emacs_
                      Related/Miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
)`

Comment: @lyl ah you need a \detokenize or locally set catcode of `_` to 12 if you have fancy characters like that

Comment: And where can I find the meaning of `kpsewhich` and `texosquery -c `? Why needs `\def\fcln{/}` and `\def\fslh{/}`?

Comment: `texdoc texosquery` and `texdoc kpsewhich ` have more information @lyl

Comment: Running `\getabsolutepath{\jobname}` obtain a typeset of `kpsewhich: security risk: running with elevated privileges ./!00-test.tex`. I'd like a typeset like /e/.../.../!00-test.tex`

Comment: why are you running with elevated privileges ?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of the error message

Comment: @lyl it is a windows operating message not a tex one, warning you are running the command as adminstrator not normal user access.

Comment: Alternative solution includes `\sys_get_shell:nnN` etc. [Write18: capturing shell (script) output as command/variable? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16790/250119) although you can't use quotes in that case. Side note, TeXlive appears to hard code `kpsewhich` or something, so for example if you execute `kpsewhich a.tex;echo 1` it will (unsafely) do the echo with shell-escape, but do nothing without -- i.e. you seems to be safe against shell injection.

Comment: @user202729 I wouldn't give an answer which requireds shell escape.

Comment: Not really, \sys_get_shell works if and only if your solution works. i.e. restricted shell escape mode

Comment: @user202729 ah sorry yes I was confused by your echo example