# How to check if different file path refer to the same file

Tags: tex-core, external-files, logic

A file may be accessed by different paths. For example,

```
 - subpath/myfile.tex
 - ./subpath/myfile.tex 
 - ../current path/subpath/myfile.tex,
 - /d/.../current path/subpath/myfile.tex
```

They refer to the same file `myfile.tex` under current path.

Given these different paths, how can I make a macro to check if they are the the same file?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\ifsamefile[4]{
 % if file #1 is in file-list #2(which is a comma list)
 % then do #3
 % else do #4
}

    \begin{document}
    \ifsamefile{myfile}{./myfile.tex,file2.tex}{true}{false} %should be true
    \ifsamefile{myfile}{../current path/myfile.tex,file2.tex}{true}{false} %should be true
    \issamefile{subpath/file1.tex}{./subpath/file1.tex,subpath/file2.tex}{true}{false} %should be true
    \issamefile{subpath/file1.tex}{/d/mypath/current path/subpath/file1.tex,./subpath/file1.tex}{true}{false} %should be true
    \end{document}
```

Comment: this is basically a duplicate of your earlier https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651007/1090  you can get the path the just compare them as token lists

Comment: Notice that this is a conceptually difficult thing depending on the operating system and filesystem. In UNIX I can `ln filea fileb` and then `filea` and `fileb` are the same file at all effects. Add in directories symbolically linked and you have a nice mess ;-).

Comment: If I `\immediate\openout1 <path1> \immediate\openout2 <path2>` for two paths to the same file, my TeX implementation produces a "Runtime error 5" and exits. Perhaps other implementations fail gracefully so that `\ifeof2` can be evaluated? That would also catch `ln filea fileb` cases.

Comment: ~~Use shell escape and some bash scripting (or Lua scripting). I think TeX doesn't really have a built-in for this.~~ I thought it was about symlinked files, but I see you only consider the same *path* instead of same file. So yes it's duplicate of your other question. You need an expandable input though. (by the way if you are serious about TeX programming I recommend reading the TeXbook/TeX by topic. Will save you some trouble (and questions) later on.)